# Como visualizar una imagen de la base de datos y luego modificarla en PHP y MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un crud para ventas de propiedades, pero se me presenta un inconveniente al modificar la imagen, quiero que cuando se modifique una propiedad en el espacio de editar imagen ya salga el nombre de la imagen proveniente de la base de datos, esto para que el usuario no tenga que elegir una nueva imagen cada vez que entra a modificar una propiedad.

Ejemplo de cómo se observa cuando entro a modificar una propiedad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo de cómo quiero que se vea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código para modificar una propiedad en el model

```
    function ModificarUnaPropiedadModel(){
      $instancia = AbrirBaseDatos();

        if(!empty($_POST["btnModificar"])){
          if(!empty($_POST["nombre"]) and !empty($_POST["provincia"])  and !empty($_POST["tipo"])  and !empty($_POST["cuartos"])  and !empty($_POST["garaje"]) 
             and !empty($_POST["banos"]) and !empty($_POST["precio"]) and !empty($_POST["descripcion"])){
              if(!empty($_POST["status"])){
                $id = $_GET["id"];
                $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
                $provincia = $_POST["provincia"];
                $tipo = $_POST["tipo"];
                $cuartos = $_POST["cuartos"];
                $garaje = $_POST["garaje"];
                $banos = $_POST["banos"];
                $precio = $_POST["precio"];
                $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
                $imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));
                $status = '1';

                $agregarPropiedad = $instancia -> query("UPDATE propiedades set nombre ='$nombre', provincia = ' $provincia', tipo = '$tipo', cuartos = $cuartos, 
                garaje = $garaje, banos= $banos, precio = $precio, descripcion = '$descripcion', imagen = '$imagen', status = '$status' WHERE id = $id ;");

              }  

              if(empty($_POST["status"])){
                $id = $_GET["id"];
                $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
                $provincia = $_POST["provincia"];
                $tipo = $_POST["tipo"];
                $cuartos = $_POST["cuartos"];
                $garaje = $_POST["garaje"];
                $banos = $_POST["banos"];
                $precio = $_POST["precio"];
                $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
                $imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));
                $status = '0';

                $agregarPropiedad = $instancia -> query("UPDATE propiedades set nombre ='$nombre', provincia = ' $provincia', tipo = '$tipo', cuartos = $cuartos, 
                garaje = $garaje, banos= $banos, precio = $precio, descripcion = '$descripcion', imagen = '$imagen', status = '$status' WHERE id = $id ;");

              } 

              if($agregarPropiedad == 1){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-succes">Se ha modificado la propiedad correctamente</div>';
              } else {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Ha ocurrido algún error, consulte con soporte técnico</div>';
              }
                      
          } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Revisa que no hayan datos vacios</div>';
          }
        }

        CerrarBaseDatos($instancia);

    }
```

Ejemplo del controller

```
    function ModificarPropiedadController(){

        $propiedad = ModificarPropiedadModel();
        $totalResult = mysqli_num_rows($propiedad);
        $searchResultHTML = '';
        if($totalResult > 0) {
            while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($propiedad)){
                
                echo  '

                <form class="mt-4 mt-md-0" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nombre</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="acadNombre" type="text" name="nombre" value="'. $item['nombre'] .'" REQUIRED/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Provincia</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="acadDireccion" type="text" name="provincia" REQUIRED>
                            <option value="'. $item['provincia'] .'">'. $item['provincia'] .'</option>
                            <option value="San José">San José</option>
                            <option value="Cartago">Cartago</option>
                            <option value="Heredia">Heredia</option>
                            <option value="Alajuela">Alajuela</option>
                            <option value="Puntarenas">Puntarenas</option>
                            <option value="Limon">Limon</option>
                            <option value="Guanacaste">Guanacaste</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Tipo</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="acadPais" type="text" name="tipo" REQUIRED>
                            <option value="'. $item['tipo'] .'">'. $item['tipo'] .'</option>
                            <option value="Casa">Casa</option>
                            <option value="Apartamento">Apartamento</option>
                            <option value="Terreno">Terreno</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Cantidad de cuartos</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="acadProvincia" type="number" name="cuartos" REQUIRED>
                            <option value="'. $item['cuartos'] .'">'. $item['cuartos'] .'</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="text">Capacidad de carros</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="acadDistrito" type="number" name="garaje" REQUIRED>
                            <option value="'. $item['garaje'] .'">'. $item['garaje'] .'</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="text">Cantidad de Baños</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="acadDistrito" type="number" name="banos" REQUIRED>
                            <option value="'. $item['banos'] .'">'. $item['banos'] .'</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="text">Precio</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="acadDistrito" type="text" name="precio" value="'. $item['precio'] .'" REQUIRED/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="text">Descripción</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="acadDistrito" type="textarea" name="descripcion" value="'. $item['descripcion'] .'" REQUIRED/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="text">Imagen</label>
                        <div class="img-box-a">
                        <br>
                            <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'. base64_encode($item['imagen']) .'" alt="Propiedades en Costa Rica" class="img-a img-fluid">
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" id="acadDistrito" type="file" name="imagen" REQUIRED/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="text">Status</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="acadDistrito" type="checkbox" name="status"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="submit-btn" id="acadSubmit" type="submit" value="Modificar" name="btnModificar">
                    </div>
                </form>
                
                ';
            
            }
        } else {
            $searchResultHTML = '<h3>No se ha encontrado ninguna propiedad..</h3>';
        }

        $searchResultHTML = '<h3>Si se ha encontrado ninguna propiedad..</h3>';

        return $searchResultHTML;   
    }

    function ModificarUnaPropiedadController(){
        $guardarInformación = ModificarUnaPropiedadModel();
      }
```

Ejemplo de la vista

```
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
   <?php ModificarUnaPropiedadController();?>
   <?php ModificarPropiedadController(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: No entiendo.. de donde viene ese nombre?? y donde lo queres agregar??

Comment: creo que tienes que asignarlo al atributo value del input la ruta de la imagen que guardaste en la bd

Comment: La imagen viene de la base de datos, al actualizar la información de la propiedad tengo que seleccioar nuevamente la imagen porque sino se guarda como null y no quiero que eso suceda. Quiero que la imagen al modificar se mantenga y solo en caso de que yo elija otra imagen entonces cambie.